# @JsonView doesn't work in a simple test

Tags: java, jackson

I can't perform this simple example with @JsonView. What am I doing wrong?

> ${jackson-2-version} = 2.6.5

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson-2-version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson-2-version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson-2-version}</version>
</dependency>
```

The full test class.

```
package staticTest;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonView;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import org.junit.Test;

/**
 * Created by Daniel on 01/04/2016.
 */
public class Jackson2Tests {

    @Test
    public void JsonViewTest(){

        try {

            System.out.println(getMapper().writeValueAsString(new DemoClass()));
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private ObjectMapper getMapper(){

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        objectMapper.writerWithView(ToShowIn.App.class);
        objectMapper.readerWithView(ToShowIn.App.class);

        return objectMapper;
    }

    public class ToShowIn {

        public class App{}
        public class Manager{}

    }

    class DemoClass{

        @JsonView(ToShowIn.App.class)
        private String propertyOne = "one";
        private int propertyTwo = 2;
        private boolean propertyThree = true;
        private DemoChild propertyFour = new DemoChild();

        public String getPropertyOne() {
            return propertyOne;
        }

        public void setPropertyOne(String propertyOne) {
            this.propertyOne = propertyOne;
        }

        public int getPropertyTwo() {
            return propertyTwo;
        }

        public void setPropertyTwo(int propertyTwo) {
            this.propertyTwo = propertyTwo;
        }

        public boolean isPropertyThree() {
            return propertyThree;
        }

        public void setPropertyThree(boolean propertyThree) {
            this.propertyThree = propertyThree;
        }

        public DemoChild getPropertyFour() {
            return propertyFour;
        }

        public void setPropertyFour(DemoChild propertyFour) {
            this.propertyFour = propertyFour;
        }

        class DemoChild{

            private String childOne = "1";
            private int childTwo = 2;
            private boolean childThree = true;

            public String getChildOne() {
                return childOne;
            }

            public void setChildOne(String childOne) {
                this.childOne = childOne;
            }

            public int getChildTwo() {
                return childTwo;
            }

            public void setChildTwo(int childTwo) {
                this.childTwo = childTwo;
            }

            public boolean isChildThree() {
                return childThree;
            }

            public void setChildThree(boolean childThree) {
                this.childThree = childThree;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Result in:

> {"propertyOne":"one","propertyTwo":2,"propertyThree":true,"propertyFour":{"childOne":"1","childTwo":2,"childThree":true}}

**SOLUTION**

First, as @varren says below, `.writerWithView()` is not a setter.

To make one view persistent in the ObjectMapper work with `.setConfig()`.

> objectMapper.setConfig(objectMapper.getSerializationConfig().withView(ToShowIn.App.class));

Finally, and the most important, `objectMapper.disable(MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION);`makes JsonView works just like jackson documentation contributed by @varren says.

Comment: One minor sidenote: use of `ObjectWriter` (and retaining reference to one) is important if you need to change the View -- with mapper, you can set the default view, but you can NOT change it after it has been set and mapper has been used for writing. But you can freely create ObjectWriters with different settings; it is designed for per-use re-configuration, whereas `ObjectMapper` is more of a factory for ObjectReaders/ObjectWriters (but with convenience methods for common operations).

Comment: That´s a good point @StaxMan, ty ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`writerWithView` and `readerWithView` are not setters, they are `ObjectWriter` and `ObjectReader` builder methods, so you have to use:

```
getMapper().writerWithView(ToShowIn.App.class).writeValueAsString(new DemoClass()))
```

And you also have to disable `MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION` for your objectMapper.

```
private ObjectMapper getMapper(){
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.disable(MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION);
    return objectMapper;
}
```

Here is info from documentation: http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJsonViews

> Handling of "view-less" properties
>
> By default all properties without explicit view definition are
>   included in serialization. But starting with Jackson 1.5 you can
>   change this default by:
>
> objectMapper.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION,
>   false); where false means that such properties are NOT included when
>   enabling with a view. Default for this property is 'true'.